# How to correlate messages sent over camel-netty component

Tags: apache-camel, netty

```
from(jetty).bean(RequestProcessor).to(netty).bean(ResponseProcessor)
```

In above route, the netty endpoint can return messages in any order based on downstream latency. Eg., The messages arrive in the order msg1, msg2 and sent over netty. Netty can receive messages in the order msg2, msg1.

1. How do we correlate messages in the above route ? What will be Exchange.CORRELATION_ID, when message arrives at ResponseProcessor ?
2. How do we reply to correct http request ?

Comment: If you use low-level Netty then you need to build in your own correlation in the codec you use with Netty and the other-party you exchange data with, there is nothing built-in out of the box when its low-level protocols.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Lets say i build a wrapper around netty, how can i correlate the exchanges and continue the pipeline ? Like storing exchange id and using custom correlation is there way to let camel know that i continuing the pipeline with specific exchange id ?